# How to make one more try function in a Unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know how can I do it. You lose a game, if gameobject falls down and collides with the collider. I want to add a function that asks to the player if he wants another try, if yes it will reverse some time so the gameobject that fall down  will be back on the screen and the user is allowed to play once again. Is there some sort of time function/method to do this?
Hope you understand.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)    {
    if(col.gameObject.tag=="Collider") {
        Vector2 checkpoint = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y +5)
    }
}   

void Reset(){       
    this.transform.position = checkpoint;   
}
```

Comment: To be able to do this you would have to implement some kind of timelapse yourself. Create something like a `Dictionary<float, List<ObjectAction>>` which will hold up actions like `PositionChangeAction : ObjectAction { ActionType actionType = ActionType.PositionY; float fromValue = 3.3f, toValue = 3.45f; Object target; }` and then after each update just add these actions to that timelapse ( `Dictionary` ).

Comment: I updated my answer with an approach that may work for your problem. Check it and let me know if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a child object for that collider. And I moved the child to where I wanted the player to live when I collided with the collider.

```
  Void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
         if(col.gameobject.tag=="die")
          {
              checkpoint = col.transform.GetChil(0).position;
          }
    }

void Reset(){
            Player.transform.position = checkpoint;
}
```

Comment: void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
 {
  if(col.gameObject.tag=="Collider")
  {
   Vector2 checkpoint = Vector2(transform.position.x ,transform.position.y +5);
    
  }
 }

 void Reset(){
  this.transform.position = checkpoint;
 } i have done it like this but now i get an error: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected

Comment: @Ignacio Alorre  is right. 

 `Vector2 checkpoint = new Vector2(transform.position.x ,transform.position.y +5);`

not 

`Vector2 checkpoint = Vector2(transform.position.x ,transform.position.y +5);`

Comment: Thanks @Hieu, and yes, "new" solve the problem he was facing, but instead of upvote or accept, he edit the question without the error. I think your answer will do the trick as well so +1 for you. But the solution of going back in time he wants doesn't exist in Unity. I updated my answer now with a possible solution to the issue he still face, but for sure he will not find anything in the Engine to save the state of the player.

Comment: I think Unity3D does not support this.
We should find the plugin that support this
Exemple: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31225.
I'm not sure its helps you. But try.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because you are missing the **new** keyword before Vector2

> When using C# you need to use the new keyword in front of all
>   constructors. Constructors are like functions that are used to create
>   new objects (or scructs). They always have the same name as the type
>   of object you are creating.

So you should write

```
Vector2 checkpoint = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y +5)
```

instead of:

```
Vector2 checkpoint = Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y +5)
```

Edit: Now you edited your question without the error, and since you are still trying to find a method that moves back in time what happened in Unity, I can tell you that that thing doesn't exist. However you can implement it yourself. I would recommend you something like this:

- If it is a platform 2D game, like Mario Bros style, you can place in
  your scene a sequence of trigger that are activated when the player
  go through them.
- Then you can have a `boolean array` with a length `n` equal to the
  number of triggers, and then a matrix nx2 ( number of triggers x
  coordinates of each trigger [x,y] ).
- Initially all the elements in the array has a `false` value, and
  every time a trigger is activated the correcponding element in the
  array changes to true.
- When the player dies, it checks all elements in the array, until it
  reaches the last true element (this would be the last triggered
  activated).
- With the index form the previous step you access the matrix of
  triggers and you extract both elements (x and y coordinate). Then you
  use that value in:

Using your script:

```
Vector2 checkpoint = new Vector2(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no in built function to reverse time in unity, this would require unity to record all events up until that point.

But given your example, what you could do is create a 'checkpoint' where the scene is set up in a certain way and objects are in specific positions. Like in Mario where you fall down, it plays some music to show you failed then it puts Mario back in a certain position. Just have a function that changes the player position to the checkpoint position. The same applies to any other gameobject you need to reset.

```
public void Reset()
{
    player.position = checkpoint.position;
}
```